# Android Studio download file form drive using API Key?

Tags: android, api, download, google-drive-api

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/Fileid?acknowledgeAbuse=false&alt=media&key=KEY

This link is working fine on browser but not in Android Studio
Using URL and URLConnection.

download file form drive using API Key in Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to refer to [Making a Simple Request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) or this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android) for this particular problem because what you want to do is not just open the link but instead make a web service request to the Drive API. Also, take note that REST calls need to be authorized. You may also want to refer to [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) documentation as there are also steps there that might help you in making the proper request.